# Unexpected JDWP Error: 103. Exception during Retrofit(2.3.0) GET call

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2

I am getting Unexpected JDWP Error: 103 during call to vk.api to fetch some data.

I have found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745875/getting-a-unexpected-jdwp-error-103-while-trying-to-upload-an-image-using-retro) with related problem, but suggestion from there is already applyed in my application.

So maybe my retrofit configuration is wrong?

Here some code:

Module for DI, using dagger

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiConstants.VK_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }

    @Provides
    internal fun provideGroupApi(retrofit: Retrofit) : GroupApi {
        return retrofit.create(GroupApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

Api interface:

```
interface GroupApi {

    @GET(ApiMethods.SEARCH_GROUPS)
    fun getGroups(@QueryMap map: Map<String, String?>) : Observable<GroupResponse>
}

object ApiMethods {

    const val SEARCH_GROUPS = "groups.search"
}
```

Inside query:

[image]

Model classes:

```
data class Response<T>(
        val count: Int,
        val items: List<T>
)

data class GroupResponse(
        @SerializedName("response")
        @Expose
        val response: Response<Group>
)

data class Group(
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        val id: Int,
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        val name: String,
        @SerializedName("screenName")
        @Expose
        val screen_name: String,
        @SerializedName("isClosed")
        @Expose
        val is_closed: Int,
        @SerializedName("type")
        @Expose
        val type: String,
        @SerializedName("isAdmin")
        @Expose
        val is_admin: Int,
        @SerializedName("isMebmer")
        @Expose
        val is_member: Int,
        @SerializedName("photo_50")
        @Expose
        val photo_50: String,
        @SerializedName("photo_100")
        @Expose
        val photo_100: String,
        @SerializedName("photo_200")
        @Expose
        val photo_200: String
)
```

Here is response example from vk.api (I am providing this, because I have a thought that my model is configured not properly):

```
 {
    "response": {
    "count": 193738,
    "items": [{
    "id": 26667550,
    "name": "ARTY",
    "screen_name": "arty_music",
    "is_closed": 0,
    "type": "page",
    "is_admin": 0,
    "is_member": 0,
    "photo_50": "https://pp.vk.me/...841/1B4wTxXinAc.jpg",
    "photo_100": "https://pp.vk.me/...840/Xc_3PikLQ_M.jpg",
    "photo_200": "https://pp.vk.me/...83e/kGwRLtSLJOU.jpg"
    }, {
    "id": 25597207,
    "name": "Alexander Popov",
    "screen_name": "popov.music",
    "is_closed": 0,
    "type": "page",
    "is_admin": 0,
    "is_member": 0,
    "photo_50": "https://pp.vk.me/...e8f/g2Z9jU6qXVk.jpg",
    "photo_100": "https://pp.vk.me/...e8e/DtYBYKLU810.jpg",
    "photo_200": "https://pp.vk.me/...e8d/QRVqdhTvQ4w.jpg"
    }, {
    "id": 42440233,
    "name": "Музыка",
    "screen_name": "exp.music",
    "is_closed": 0,
    "type": "page",
    "is_admin": 0,
    "is_member": 0,
    "photo_50": "https://pp.vk.me/...2d1/52gY6m5ZObg.jpg",
    "photo_100": "https://pp.vk.me/...2d0/Jx9DWph_3ag.jpg",
    "photo_200": "https://pp.vk.me/...2ce/qsFhk6yEtDc.jpg"
    }]
   }
 }
```

Could anybody please provide any suggestion ?

**UPDATE:**

I am also have tried another response model as:

```
data class Root<T> (
    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    val response: T
    )

interface GroupApi {

    @GET(ApiMethods.SEARCH_GROUPS)
    fun getGroups(@QueryMap map: Map<String, String?>) : Observable<Root<Response<Group>>>
}
```

but still no luck...

**additional code:**

Presenter where I call the interactor -> and inside interactor I call GroupApi:

```
class SearchResultPresenter<V : SearchResultMVPView, I : SearchResultMVPInteractor> @Inject constructor(interactor: I, schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider, compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable)
    : BasePresenter<V, I>(interactor = interactor, schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider, compositeDisposable = compositeDisposable), SearchResultMVPPresenter<V, I> {

    override fun searchGroups(q: String) {
        getView()?.showProgress()
        interactor?.let {
            compositeDisposable.add(it.getGroupList(q)
                    .compose(schedulerProvider.ioToMainObservableScheduler())
                    .subscribe { groupResponse ->
                        getView()?.let {
                            it.showSearchResult(groupResponse.response.items)
                            it.hideProgress()
                        }
                    })
        }
    }
}

class SearchResultInteractor @Inject constructor() : SearchResultMVPInteractor {

    @Inject
    lateinit var groupApi: GroupApi

    override fun getGroupList(q: String): Observable<Root<Response<Group>>> = groupApi.getGroups(GroupRequest(q).toMap())

}
```

I have decided to provide the whole code, where I am applying DI:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(AndroidInjectionModule::class), (AppModule::class), (ActivityBuilder::class)])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MyApplication)
}
```

Module for fragment:

```
@Module
class SearchResultFragmentModule {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideSearchResultInteractor(interactor: SearchResultInteractor): SearchResultMVPInteractor = interactor

    @Provides
    internal fun provideSearchResultFragment(presenter: SearchResultPresenter<SearchResultMVPView, SearchResultMVPInteractor>)
            : SearchResultMVPPresenter<SearchResultMVPView, SearchResultMVPInteractor> = presenter

    @Provides
    internal fun provideSearchResultProvider(): SearchResultAdapter = SearchResultAdapter(ArrayList())

    @Provides
    internal fun provideLayoutManager(fragment: SearchResultFragment) : LinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(fragment.activity)
}
```

Provider:

```
@Module
abstract class SearchResultFragmentProvider {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [(SearchResultFragmentModule::class), (NetworkModule::class)])
    internal abstract fun proviceSearchResultFragmentModule(): SearchResultFragment
}
```

Activity that contains injector for fragments inside of it:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), MainMVPView, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var presenter: MainMVPPresenter<MainMVPView, MainMVPInteractor>
    @Inject
    internal lateinit var fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

...
//some code
override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> = fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector
}
```

And activity builder:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [(MainActivityModule::class), (SearchResultFragmentProvider::class)])
    abstract fun bindMainActibity(): MainActivity
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(AndroidInjectionModule::class), (AppModule::class), (ActivityBuilder::class)])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MyApplication)
}
```

Comment: Can you also post how you are sending the asynchronous network call using Retrofit.

Comment: @keshavAggarwal I've posted it, but I think no matter how I call it, because I am testing it in debug mode. I am just calling `groupApi.getGroups(GroupRequest(q).toMap())` to test and I am getting this error.

Comment: Try constructor injection of GroupApi, You are injecting it in `class SearchResultInteractor` but you are not specifying the component you are injecting it from.

Comment: @keshavAggarwal I've provided the whole code example. (in additional). Could you please explain what do I exacly have to write inside constructor for `class SearchResultInteractor`

Comment: @keshavAggarwal, do you mean that  I have to write it like:  `class SearchResultInteractor @Inject constructor(val groupApi: GroupApi)` 
 something like that ?

Comment: Yes. try it once.

Comment: @keshavAggarwal, unfortunately still it's not working. even if I initialize Retrofit right in the place where I am making service call - exception appears.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inject retrofit (instead of GroupApi) and then call
retrofit.create(GroupApi::class.java).getGroups(GroupRequest(q).toMap())
in your SearchResultInteractor? Also you can annotate fun provideRetrofit() as Singleton.

Comment: Have you created a component for your Dagger module and do you initialise it somewhere?

Comment: I have provided the whole code example, where I am applyig DI. Could you please check it ?

Comment: I still cannot understand your dependency graph. There should be a component, that includes your networkModule (the one with retrofit), and all your modules to bind view (fragments and activities) to modules the're using (in your case it's SearchResultFragmentProvider and alike, which are still modules, not providers). Then this component must be initialised in your application class, i.e.   appComponent = DaggerYourAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't provided app component class, please find it at hte end of provided code.

Answer (score 0):

If some one still watching this post - I am sorry, I've made a mistake.

Retrofit is working properly, the issue was in uninitialized view at presenter class, so when I was calling api method `groupApi.getGroups(GroupRequest(q).toMap())` in debug - exception was appearing. But problem was in view class.